# Images sent from React Native has size zero

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, multer, expo-camera

I've written the code below to send an image from react native expo through a post request to my backend. I have tested the backend with postman and confirmed it's working. However, when I make a post request to send an image, the image is received on the backend with size 0.
Before making the post request, I logged the file size and confirm it's not zero.

```
export const uploadVerificationPhoto = async (photoUri: string) => {
  try {
    const blob = await fetch(photoUri).then((r) => r.blob());

    const file = new File([blob], `photo.jpeg`, { type: blob.type });
   
    console.log("file:", file.size); //result > 0

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("driverID", "63cf8420cd6d7a41da6dad91");
    formData.append("driverImage", file, "photo.jpeg");

    const response = await axios.post(
      "http://localhost:10001/api/image/profile-photo",
      formData,
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      }
    );
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error sending photos:", error);
    throw error;
  }
};
```

I tried sending the file as base64 but expo file sytem threw `uri cannot be read` error.
I thought the issue was multer on my backend so I used formidable instead and I was still getting the same issue.
This issue happens whether I pick an image or take a photo with expo camera.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with React Native Profile Images, here is the solution from my project:

```
// Your backend route:

userProfileImages: async (req, res) => {
    const file = req.file;
    try {
      if (!file) {
        return res
          .status(400)
          .json({ success: false, message: "No file provided." });
      }

      const filePath = file.path;
      // console.log(req.file);
      const userId = req.user.id;

      const fileStats = fs.statSync(filePath);
      console.log("File Path: " + filePath);
      console.log("File stats:", fileStats);
      console.log("Form Data: ", JSON.stringify(req.body));
      if (fileStats.size > 0) {
        const image = new Image({
          userId: userId,
          name: file.originalname,
          imageUrl: file.path,
          contentType: file.mimetype,
          size: fileStats.size,
        });
        // console.log("File stats size: " + fileStats.size);
        // console.log("Req file size: " + req.file.size);
        await image.save();

        return res.status(201).json({
          success: true,
          message: "Image created successfully.",
          imageName: file.originalname,
          size: fileStats.size,
        });
      } else {
        return res
          .status(500)
          .json({ success: false, message: "File is empty." });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error handling image:", error);
      return res
        .status(500)
        .json({ success: false, message: "Internal server error." });
    }
  },
```

```
// You React component

  const pickImageAsync = async () => {
    try {
      const { status } =
        await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== "granted") {
        return Alert.alert("Sorry, we need your permissions");
      }

      const result: any = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
        allowsEditing: true,
        aspect: [4, 3],
        quality: 1,
      });

      if (result.cancelled) {
        return;
      }

      const selectedAsset = result.assets[0];

      setSelectedImage({
        uri: selectedAsset.uri,
        width: selectedAsset.width || null,
        height: selectedAsset.height || null,
        type: selectedAsset.type || null,
        fileSize: selectedAsset.fileSize || null,
        fileName: selectedAsset.filename || null,
      });

      const localUri = selectedAsset.uri;
      const fileName = localUri.split("/").pop();
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("file", {
        uri: selectedAsset.uri,
        type: "image/jpeg",
        name: fileName || "image.jpg",
      } as any);
      await deleteImage();
      await postImage(formData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error in pickImageAsync:", error);
    }
  };

  const postImage = async (formData: FormData) => {
    try {
      await axios.post("http://localhost:8000/upload", formData, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${storedToken}`,
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      });
      // console.log("Upload Response:", response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error in postImage:", error);
    }
  };
```